# Sanitizing HTML string in Angular removes formatting from attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm experimenting a little and making a function to dynamically build the fields of a form.
The thing is, at first the sanitizer in Angular removes `<input>` tags, so I found out that I can bypass that for the string that contains the HTML code.
The problem is, I need to bind an attribute to that `<input>` but after bypassing the santizer, the attribute is transformed to all lowercase. Here is all the code:

**FormBuilder**

```js
import { FormItem } from "./formItem.interface"

export const FormFieldsBuilder = (fields: FormItem[]): string => {
    let htmlString: string = ''

    fields.forEach(field => {
        let attributes = field.htmlTagAttributes?.join(' ')
        let baseString = `

            <div class="${field.fieldContainerClass}">
                <div class="${field.fieldClass}">
                    <label for="${field.name}" >${field.label}</label>
                    <${field.htmlTag} ${attributes} 
                        class="${field.htmlTagClass}" 
                        formControlName="${field.name}">
                    </${field.htmlTag}>
                </div>
            </div>

        `

        htmlString += baseString
    });

    return htmlString
}
```

**New product form component**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductsService } from '../../../api/services/products.service';
import { FormItem } from '../../../shared/helpers/FormFieldsBuilder/formItem.interface';
import { FormFieldsBuilder } from '../../../shared/helpers/FormFieldsBuilder/formFieldsBuilder';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-product',
  templateUrl: './new-product.component.html',
  styleUrl: './new-product.component.scss'
})
export class NewProductComponent {
  uploadedFiles: File[] = [];
  formData : FormData = new FormData()
  mainProductFields: FormItem[] = []
  fieldsString: string = ''

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private productsService: ProductsService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.mainProductFields = [
      { 
        label: 'Nombre', 
        name: 'name', 
        htmlTag: 'input', 
        htmlTagClass: 'w-full', 
        fieldContainerClass: 'col-12 lg:col-6 pb-0',
        fieldClass: 'field w-full flex flex-column gap-2',
        htmlTagAttributes: [
          'pInputText'
        ]
      }
    ]

    this.fieldsString = FormFieldsBuilder(this.mainProductFields)
  }

  
  public get formFields() : SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.fieldsString)
  }

  // Other irrelevant code...
}
```

**New form component html**

```html
<div class="grid" [innerHTML]="formFields">
```

So, the attribute should be **pInputText** but after sanitizing it gets transformed into **pinputtext**
Is there a way to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML attributes change to lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554012/html-attributes-change-to-lower-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create HTML strings that bind to Angular.

If you want to achieve that, Angular [has a full tutorial for that](https://angular.dev/guide/forms/dynamic-forms).